# How can I search for a specific user on the People administration page?

Tags: users, search

I can filter by Role, Permission and status on the people page, is there an easy way to search for one specific user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's all you can do with core Drupal - it is a little frustrating for sure.  :-)

However, there are lots of contrib modules that let you do more, such as

- [Advanced User](http://drupal.org/project/advuser), in which user fields to filter/search by can be configured in the module's settings or
- the simpler [User search to People Admin](http://drupal.org/project/usersearchtoadmin) which simply puts the user search box on there for you.

Of course, you can also opt to make yourself a user-based view and create an admin page yourself by using relationships and filters.  :-)

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: Thank you, seems like a pretty 'Core' requirement to me, I'll check out the modules.

Comment: Yeah, all of us who use Drupal daily have wanted more from the user admin page, believe me. :-)  The good thing is - that's the whole point of contrib modules, and there are so many of them.

Comment: If only it was as easy to contib to a contrib module as it is to contrib to a github repo :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this question is about D7, only using Drupal core wont be sufficient. However, you could create a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) of all your users, and use the views style provided by the [dataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) module. Here is a quote from the dataTables project page:

> The DataTables module integrates the jQuery plugin DataTables into Drupal as a views style and a callable theme function. DataTables lets you add dynamic features to tables, including:
>
> - Variable length pagination
> - On-the-fly filtering
> - Sorting with data type detection
> - Smart handling of column widths
> - Themeable by CSS
> - And more ...

You'd be especially interested in the ***On-the-fly filtering***. For way more details about this module, refer to "[What are my options to visualise a views table with many fields grouped in columns?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169453/what-are-my-options-to-visualise-a-views-table-with-many-fields-grouped-in-colum/169466#169466)".

Answer (score 0):

I want to also vouch for https://www.drupal.org/project/usersearchtoadmin in Drupal 7. I used such and had great success for specific people keyword searches "as shown" in the real life example below:

[image: User Search For People Administration Example]